# Sql поиск по нескольким полям, когда какое-то поле может быть пустым

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать фильтрацию. Есть 3 значения "имя", "дата от", "дата до".

Если убрать всё лишнее, у меня вот такая картина:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM main WHERE nameclient LIKE :who AND (datestart BETWEEN :datestart AND :dateend) ';
$pdo_statement->bindValue(':who',$name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo_statement->bindValue(':datestart',$dstart, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo_statement->bindValue(':dateend',$dend, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$pdo_statement->execute();
$result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
```

переменные who, dstart и dend я получаю из формы.
Проблема состоит в том, что какое-то из полей формы, будь это имя или диапазон дат, может быть не заполнено. Сейчас, в моём случае, если какое-то из полей не заполнить, то вернётся пустой результат.

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы sql игнорировал пустые поля?

Comment: формируйте запрос частями и привязку выполняйте частями. `$sql='SELECT * FROM main WHERE 1=1;  if($name) $sql.= ' AND nameclient LIKE :who'; ... if($name) $pdo_statement->bindValue(':who',$name, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: костыль какой-то... А разве в php нет такой встроенной функции?

Comment: `WHERE ( ( field [= | LIKE | BETWEEN | etc.] :value ) OR ( :value = '' ) ) AND ...`

Comment: Ну в таком виде костыль конечно. но если вместо bindValue использовать передачу массива параметров то довольно красиво выходит. `$sql=...; $params=array(); if(isset($name)) { $sql.=" AND nameclient like ?'; push($params, $name); } ... ->execute($params);`. И возможно дальнейшая оптимизация, вроде перебора возможных параметров в цикле

Comment: @Akina а если все поля пустые? Между чем он будет выбирать?

Comment: Если все поля пустые, то фильтр пуст, и надо вывести всё. И именно так и получится.

Comment: @Akina не получается так, как вы говорите. Я могу указать то, чего в принципе нет, и мне отобразится всё.

Comment: Нет, не только вы столкнулись с такой проблемой, с ней сталкиваются все, кто делает динамические условия. И решения у проблемы всего два: или как я предлагаю или как @Akina с помощью условий `OR :X is NULL`. А если даты только одна задана, это надо явно IF проверить и сгенерировать в запросе вместо between соответственно отдельно операторы больше и меньше. И between тогда вообще не нужен, потому что он отлично заменится условием `datestart >= :start AND datestart <= :end`

Comment: @mike вроде разобрался с вариантом Akina, но у меня возникла проблема `(datestart BETWEEN :datestart AND :dateend) OR
 (datestart >= :datestart AND datestart <= '2006-01-01') OR
 (datestart >= '2017-12-01' AND datestart <= :dateend)` . Когда "от" и "до" — всё работает, когда только "до" — работает, а когда только "от", то вообще ничего не показывает. Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: @firebear - Последнее предложение Mike прочитайте. И читайте до тех пор, пока не поймете, что нужно сделать) Суть примерно в том, что в mysql не поддерживаются в самом деле именованные параметры запроса (или как они называются), и PDO их сам подменяет на вопросики (которые работают в mysql), но случай с несколькими одинаковыми параметрами у него обрабатывается некорректно.

Comment: @firebear, я при этом не хотел сказать, что не нужно использовать такие параметры - они во многих случаях намного удобнее (как минимум для читабельности и уменьшения кол-ва ошибок). Но когда Вам нужно подставить в разные места один и тот же параметр, то можно передать несколько раз один и тот же параметр (под разными именами)